# Stop end date being before start date?

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript code I have two buttons that allow a start button to be pressed, then an end button and it will calculate the time difference.

```
// starts the timer
function startTimer() {
  startTime = new Date();
  alert(startTime);
}


// finishes the timer
function endTimer() {
  endTime = new Date();
  alert(endTime);
}
```

How can I add it so that the stop button cannot be pressed if the start button has not been pressed first? I'm new to JavaScript, so kind of lost here!

Ideally on the stop I'd like to add an alert to say that if the end date is before the start date, or if the start date hasn't been pressed, that they must start the timer before finishing the timer.

Comment: Also worthy of note, it has to be JS - no HTML.

Comment: Where are the two buttons? In CSS huh?

Comment: You could grab the buttons in js and set the appropriate ones to disabled/enabled when needed.

Comment: `it has to be JS - no HTML` just as well, because HTML doesn't even know what a Date is

Comment: I basically meant that if there's a way to hide the button in HTML, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some state to take care of this:

```
var pressedStart = false;

// starts the timer
function startTimer() {
  pressedStart = true;
  startTime = new Date();
  alert(startTime);
}


// finishes the timer
function endTimer() {
  if(!pressedStart) {
    return;
  }

  endTime = new Date();
  pressedStart = false;
  alert(endTime);
}
```

This will disable the functionality of the button in the JavaScript (it won't show an alert), but if you want to make the button appear disabled (style-wise), you can also do this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfMyButton").disabled = true;
```

Comment: Sheesh, I forgot this way! LoL.

Comment: Hey, yea, when the OP says there's no HTML, then how does the `document` come into play? `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar lol, well there has to be HTML if there's a button to be clicked :P. I assume he meant he wants the *behavior* of disabling the button to exist in JavaScript (rather than the disabling behavior to exist as part of the HTML).

Comment: It's basically just a HTML editor, let me see if I can get this working! I'll get back to you, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can initially disable the button using disable attribute and then  in your function you can simply write as :

```
function startTimer() {
 document.getElementById("YourButtonId").disabled = false;
  startTime = new Date();
  alert(startTime);
}
```

Comment: Another good idea, I'll give them both a shot now. Thank you!